# How to account for error in measurement of dependent variable in prediction interval (in multiple regression)?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval

I am trying to figure out the best way to take into account known measurement error in the Y (dependent) variable when producing prediction intervals from a multiple regression. I have the standard model

$y = X\beta + \epsilon$

Where each observation in y is measured with known error $se_y$.

I am attempting to create prediction interval for predicted values using the standard formula for the variance in $\hat(y)$:

$Var(\hat{y}) = s^2(1 + X_0(X'X)^{-1}X_0')  $

and thus the predictive interval

$\hat{y_0} \pm T_{1-\alpha/2,N-(k+1)} * \sqrt{Var(\hat{y})} $

What I am struggling with is how to account for the known measurement error in y. In practice, the measurement error of Y is large compared to the variance of $\hat{y}$ and so ignoring it seems to produce a predictive interval that is inappropriately narrow.

It is very important to me to be able to show that our results are uncertain not just due to the regression line but due to uncertainty in measuring y.

I have considered modifying $s^2$ to account for the additional known measurement error, or simply adding the $Var(y)$ to the $Var(\hat{y})$ in the prediction interval formula: but neither approach seems clearly mathematically justifiable.

Comment: Please have a look at "estimating regression models in which the dependent variable is based on estimates" by Lewis and Linzer (2005).